# Replace an element with a wrapped new one

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to replace an old element with a wrapped new one.

I begin like this:

```
<div>Some text
  <span id="old"></span>
</div>
```

And I want this:

```
<div>Some text
  <span>
    <a></a>
  </span>
</div>
```

I manage to replace the old element with the new one like this:

```
var elementA = document.querySelector('#old')
var elementB = document.createElement("a")
elementA.before(elementB)
elementA.remove()
```

Result:

```
<div>Some text
  <a></a>
</div>
```

But I cannot manage to wrap the new element in the meantime. I tried to override `Element.outerHTML`, and jQuery `wrap()`, without success. Any idea please?

EDIT: I noticed I oversimplified my use case... here is the more precise code:

```
var elementA = document.querySelector('#old')
var elementB = document.createElement("a")

// Here I do manipulations on elementB: add classes, set Id, set attributes, set innerHTML, etc.

elementA.before(elementB)
elementA.remove()
```

So `elementB` is really an "element" (or node?), not just HTML. Maybe I can turn this element into raw HTML and insert it in the wrapper with `innerHTML` as per suggestions below?
If you want to look at the actual code [here it is](https://github.com/algosphere/algo-website/blob/improve-footnotes/assets/scripts/misc.js#L68-L102).

Comment: So you want the old <span>-Element to be wrapped into another <span>-Element?

Comment: Or do you want to remove the old one completly and replace it with "<span><span></span></span>"?

Comment: added solution as per mention what you want in description.

Comment: @moviemusic1 I want to remove the old one completly and replace it with...

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer, please look at the answers :).

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I updated my question, I noticed I oversimplified my use case...

Answer (score 1):

```js
var elementA = document.querySelector('#old')
var elementB = document.createElement("span")
elementB.innerHTML = '<span></span>';
elementA.before(elementB)
elementA.remove()
```

```html
<div>Some text
  <span id="old"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

You don't need to change the HTML for this...

```
var elementA = document.querySelector('#old');
var elementB = document.createElement("span");
elementB.innerHTML = '<span></span>';
elementA.before(elementB);
elementA.remove()
```

Comment: upvoting this same thoughts one different timing.